# Computing the genus of $y^2z=x^3$ using differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, sheaf-cohomology

In [Vakil's](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, example 21.2.7 he takes the curve $y^2=x^3-x$ in $\Bbb{A}_k^2$ (with $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$) and defining $A:=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x)$ he shows that $\widetilde{\Omega}_{A|k}$ is an invertible sheaf.

He writes $2ydy=3x^2dx$ and notices that $\Omega_{A|k}$ is generated by $dx$ when $y\neq 0$ and generated by $dy$ when $3x^2-1\neq 0$. Since $\{y\neq 0\}$ and $\{3x^2-1\neq 0\}$ cover the whole curve, that's enough.

It's nice to look at things this way and I wonder if I could do something like that for different purposes.

For example, could I find the geometric genus $p_g=\dim H^0(X,\Omega_{X|k})$ for a given projective curve $X\subset \Bbb{P}^2$?

I tried to take the curve $y^2z=x^3$ in $\Bbb{P}^2_{(x:y:z)}$. Taking each affine chart, we have:
\begin{align*}
z=1&:\,\,2y=3x^2dx\\
y=1&:\,\,dz=3x^2dx\\
x=1&:\,\,2yzdy+y^2dz=0
\end{align*}

I was expecting to find $p_g=0$ (since a singular plane cubic is rational), but I don't know how to see that by the equations above.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but surely $\Omega_{X|k}$ is not an invertible sheaf in this example, since $X$ is singular?

Comment: You want to deduce that there are no global differentials, i.e. show that if you transform a regular differential like $dx$ to the other affine charts you will always get a pole at infinity. Another thing you could try (which is basically equivalent but could potentially make the bookkeeping less confusing) is writing out the Cech complex for this sheaf (the Wiki article on Cech coh. does the example of $\Omega_{\mathbb P^1}^1$). Although as @KennyWong points out, the cotangent sheaf of a cuspidal curve isn't a bundle so you really should blow up, which would make this much more annoying.

Comment: @TabesBridges (and KennyWong) I didn't know that $X$ being singular implied $\Omega_{X|k}$ not invertible. What's the reason for that? I don't understand why this is a problem

Comment: @rmdmc89 I suppose the simplest way to think about it is in terms of the Zariski cotangent space $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$. You can compute that this gadget is $2$-dimensional at a singular point of a plane curve, so the rank of the fiber of the cotangent sheaf jumps up at the singular point. For nodal curves there is a simple enough solution; instead use the dualizing sheaf (i.e. the sheaf that makes Serre duality work). For a nodal curve, the dualizing sheaf...(cont'd)

Comment: ...is obtained by looking at rational $1$-forms on the normalization and taking the subsheaf of forms which, at the two points over the node, have residues summing to $0$. Now pushforward to the nodal curve and you have the dualizing sheaf. The key point being that for nodal curves this IS an invertible sheaf. For cusps I'm not sure if there is a totally satisfactory solution.

Comment: @TabesBridges, I will need to meditate on that. Meanwhile, maybe I should try a less problematic example like $yz=x^2$. Could you explain how that would work?

Comment: @TabesBridges, I'm working on $yz=x^2$. I'll start with the regular differential $\omega:=dz$, which is both defined on  $U_x:=\{z\neq 0\}$ and $U_y$. Now on $U_z$ it looks like $d\left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)=\frac{2x}{y}dx-\frac{x^2}{y^2}dy$. It has a pole in $y=0$, so $\omega$ can not be extended to a global regular form, correct?

Comment: @TabesBridges is that argument sufficient? I mean, I could have started with a different local regular form, like $f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ where $f,g$ are polynomials. How can I guarantee that it in general this cannot be extended regularly?

Comment: @rmdmc89 Notice that by your computation, $zdz$ transforms to $\frac{2x^3}{y^2}dx - \frac{x^4}{y^3}dy$. In other words, trying somehow to clear denominators before transforming only makes the poles worse. I don't have a clear way off the top of my head to extend this to a proper argument, but do you see the idea?